# How is this possible? Maximum subarray sum

Tags: python-3.x

If there is arr = [1, 2, 3] so len(arr) is 3 right?

```
for i in range(0, len(arr)+1):
    print(arr[i])
```

It is no secret that you can not do that, simply IndexError: list index out of range.

So how is this possible?

```
def max_sequence(arr):
    if arr:
        li = []

        x = {sum(arr[i:j]): arr[i:j] for i in range(0, len(arr))
             for j in range(1, len(arr)+1)}
        li.append(max(x.items()))

        for ii in li:
            print(ii)

        return li[0][0]
    else:
        return 0


print(max_sequence([26, 5, 3, 30, -15, -7, 10, 20, 22, 4]))
```

I simply had to find the maximum sum of a contiguous subsequence in a list of integers.

If I write this part:

```
x = {sum(arr[i:j]): arr[i:j] for i in range(0, len(arr))
                 for j in range(1, len(arr))}
```

It shows that maximum sum is 94, that is incorrect.

If I write this:

```
x = {sum(arr[i:j]): arr[i:j] for i in range(0, len(arr))
     for j in range(1, len(arr)+1)}
```

Maximum sum is 98, it is correct. But why is so? If I write "for j in **range(1, len(arr)+1**)" why there is no IndexError?

Answer (score 0):

We can generate a sequence of numbers using range() function. Range(10) will generate numbers from 0 to 9 (10 numbers).

We can also define the start, stop and step size as range(start, stop,step_size).

Here in your example, "for j in range(1, len(arr)+1)"
len(arr) is 10.
So range will generate numbers from 1 to 10.

Also, your li is an empty array so its length can be varied. You are storing the result i.e. the sum in li array as well as it will store the original array and this j will help it to store it.